# Code::Blocks Find Window Closing

Tags: text, ide, codeblocks

I was wondering if there is a way to keep the "Find" window open in Codeblocks IDE (I'm using v13.12 if that's relevant). I'm talking about the window that usually opens (in any IDE) when you hit 'cntrl + F'. In Codeblocks it keeps closing everytime I hit 'Find'. I would rather it stay open like in Eclipse, Notepad++, and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally use the "Find in files" function instead of the normal Find function.

When pressing Ctrl+F select the second tab in the window and you will find "Find in Files".
Normally I use the scope "Project files" which limits the search to the project only.

After a search you will be provided with all the results in the bottom log window in the tab "Search results". You can then easily click around on all matches and C::B will jump to the file and location.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll just have to get use to another format, but this method works quite nicely too.

Comment: That's a useful alternative, but doesn't answer the OP's question. The `Find` as well as the `Find in files` windows both close after prerssing the `Find` button.